# Now able to handle autocomplete dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, autocomplete, dropdown

**Handle Autocorrect Dropdown in Java Selenium**
I am facing one issue when handling autocorrect dropdown, when testing manually the dropdown is working fine but when i execute the test ,and sendkeys some text the dropdown gives no suggestion, i triesby adding some wait but still not working, please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

If you are know the option just type the complete option value using send keys. Then use sendKeys(Keys.RETURN) to the same object and try.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. While entering text manually using keyboard, it shows the auto-complete suggestions but with Selenium it doesn't. So in case of selenium, Firstly you need to enter the required text in the input field and then use **down arrow** in send keys. e.g.:

```
element.sendKeys("Required Text");    
element.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Make sure that locator for element is exactly pointing to the input field (not it's parent elements or some other elements). You might need to give a small wait after entering text and after clicking on down arrow, So that field loads it's content. You can also try using some other arrow functions or different keys like **Keys.ENTER**.